# "int" variables and Split

Tags: python, date, datetime, variables, split

I'm recently encountering a problem with a Python script that I found on StackOverflow.

This script would be useful to take date from an input and while using it, I get the following error :

```
(year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('-'))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split')
```

The script is the following :

```
date_entry = input('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format')
year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('-'))
datewrite = datetime.date(year, month, day)
```

Comment: What input causes this error?

Comment: It is meant for an input like 2017-08-23, otherwise it wont work.

Comment: probably you're using python 2 an the `input()` function is not getting a string

Comment: Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` if you're on Python 2.x.  2.x `input()` is the equivalent of `eval(raw_input())`, so your date input was being interpreted as the subtraction of three integers.

Answer (score 4):

On Python 2.x you must use `raw_input()` instead.

But you should be using [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) regardless.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `input()` function that you call in python2.x gives you a number. To get a string you should use the raw_input( ) function.

You can also typecast the raw_input() to a number or a number to a string after the input( ) by

```
a = raw_input() 
a_num = int(raw_input( )) #or
a_num = eval(raw_input())
a_num= input()
a_num_as_string = str(a_num) ;
```

Comment: Converting to a string after `input()` doesn't help since if the input is a valid mathematical expression then Python will evaluate it.